# Double.Min_Value not working as expected

Tags: java

I have the following code, but it doesn't go through the if when `mutuaInformation` is zero. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
        int largestEntropyIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double largestMutualInfomation = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            String attrName=this.attributes.get(i);
            double conditionalEntropy = calcConditionalEntropy(i,
                                                               instances,
                                                               this.attributeValues.get(attrName).size(),
                                                               this.labels.size());

            System.out.println("conditional entropy is: "+conditionalEntropy);
            double mutualInformation = entropy - conditionalEntropy;
            if (mutualInformation > largestMutualInfomation){
                largestMutualInfomation = mutualInformation;
                largestEntropyIndex = i;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double.MIN_VALUE` holds a positive number, so `0 < Double.MIN_VALUE`.

```
/**
 * A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type
 * <code>double</code>, 2<sup>-1074</sup>. It is equal to the
 * hexadecimal floating-point literal
 * <code>0x0.0000000000001P-1022</code> and also equal to
 * <code>Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L)</code>.
 */
public static final double MIN_VALUE = 0x0.0000000000001P-1022; // 4.9e-324
```

You should use some arbitrary negative value instead (or perhaps `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`).

Answer (score 2):

The constant `Double.MIN_VALUE` equals `4.9E-324`. which, although very small, is still bigger than absolute 0.

Answer (score 2):

Execute simple code and you should get it

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Min value for Double : " + Double.MIN_VALUE);
    if(0 > Double.MIN_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("0 is greater than Double.MIN_VALUE");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("0 is less than Double.MIN_VALUE");
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Min value for Double : 4.9E-324
0 is less than Double.MIN_VALUE
```

As you see the value for `Double.MIN_VALUE` is more more than 0. Hence you notice that behavior.